# How to export png from Illustrator without anti-aliasing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, raster, anti-aliasing

On first image yow can see an icon, a line is selected in Adobe Illustrator.
On second image you can see the image after `Save for Web ..` was pressed.

I do not need anti-aliasing, extra strip between gray and black spaces. How can I turn off anti-aliasing in `Illustrator`?

[image]
[image]

## UPDATE

I am now confused, it seems that pictures are not anti-aliased, but `Preview` anti-aliase it.

But if I check it with magnifier, I can see that it it not aliased.

[image]

`Save for Web ..` has a setting too, that has an effect on anti aliasing
[image]

Comment: Do you want to delete your question as obsolete? If yes I will delete my answer to allow you to delete the Question.

Comment: I am not sure what is the situation, we should keep Q and A, It might help others.

Answer (score 4):

Try to save via Export function - you will see the options for PNG including anti-aliasing switching off:

[image]